# How to emit signal in context of specific QML Item from C++ code

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have two QML items with the same *interface* (signals emitted and handled) and different `objectName` property values:

```
Text {
    id: the_first_item
    objectName: "the_first_item"

    signal ping();

    onPing: {
        text = "pong! (variant 1)"
    }
}

Text {
    id: the_second_item
    objectName: "the_second_item"

    signal ping();

    onPing: {
        text = "pong! (variant 2)"
    }
}
```

**I want to emit the `ping` signal in context of one of these items.** In QML i would do it this way:

```
Item {
    onSomething: the_first_item.ping()
}
```

The problem is that **I want to do it from C++ code**. I have a pointer to instance of the `QQuickItem` class retrieved using `findChild` method and value of `objectName` property.

The only solution for handling signals triggered from the C++ code I have found was to define its own `QObject` derivative, declare a signal method in its body and then simply invoke it in context of an instance of this class:

```
class SomeLogic : public QObject
{
public signals:
    void ping();

public:
    void doSth() { ping(); }
};
```

Then, put a pointer to instance of this class in the engine's root context and connect a handler to this signal in QML in a following way:

```
Text {
    id: the_first_item
    //objectName: "the_first_item"

    Connections {
        target: the_instance_of_some_logic_property_name
        onPing: {
            text = "pong!"
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not good if I understand things correctly, because if `the_second_item` is defined in the same way, both of them will handle the `ping` signal emitted by `the_instance_of_some_logic_property_name` and I would like to trigger only one of them.

Now, while I am writing it, I think that maybe providing an utility function in each of items and then emit the `ping` signal in its own context, like that:

```
Text {
    id: the_first_item
    objectName: "the_first_item"

    signal ping();

    onPing: {
        text = "pong!"
    }

    function emitPing() {
        ping()
    }
}
```

In a simplier case, the `emitPing` would be enough (I wouldn't have to define the signal nor handler - I will just set the text in the `emitPing` function) but if I understand things correctly, the difference between *function* and *signal* is that the function invocation is synchronous while the signal is asynchronous and for some reasons (transistions between GUI states initiated from QML but handled in C++) I would like it to be asynchronous. I would also want to avoid necessity to write the no-brainer `emitPing` function everywhere.

**Question**: Is there a way to emit the `ping` signal, from the C++ code, in context of `the_first_item` only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it helped as a comment, now as an answere:

You can emit signals of any QObject using Qts MetaObject System. In this case, to emit the `ping` signal of `the_first_item`, just call `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(the_first_item, "ping");`

More informations about the whole meta object mechanisms can be found here: [The Meta-Object System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Thats why I'm here :D